# Why is nl.wikipedia.org referred to as Carribean Stud Poker on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, wikipedia

In my newsfeed I saw someone posting [this Wikipedia article](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci). 
When I clicked on the arrow on the post for the dropdown menu I saw the following:

[image]

Why is the author of this Wikipedia post identified as `Carribean Stud Poker`?

When I click on the arrow of another post from another author the name of the poster does make sense (it matches the source link name):

[image]

So where does the name `Carribean Stud Poker` come from?

Answer (score 1):

There is [an article on Caribbean Stud Poker on nl.wikipedia](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caribbean_Stud_Poker), but there doesn't seem to be anything remarkable about it.

I thought it might have been featured on the Main Page of nl.wikipedia or something like that, but I didn't find anything.

The only explanation I can think of is that somebody linked to that article once on Facebook and Facebook used the title of that page as the name of the whole site.